# Quick Cache - Internet Explorer Behavior

Tags: wordpress

I'm using the Quick Cache plugin for wordpress and it completely caches the PHP for a page regardless of my settings when using Internet Explorer, where as for fire fox it doesn't.

Any clue why it works like this? For record I'm not logged on as admin on both browsers.

Also, I've got wp-content included as a exception. What else can I do to get it from caching my plugin's PHP?

Answer (score 2):

Try WP Super Cache: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-super-cache/  It's more supported and updated and has better options for excluding directories and file types, such as php files in Wordpress directories or standalone files.

Be sure you don't have any cache control settings in .htaccess that might be conflicting with any cache plugin you're using.

Also, check your IE cache settings. If you're seeing caching only in IE, it's an IE setting. Cache plugins don't browser sniff.

Answer (score 0):

After more research I was able to solve my problem for both wp super cache and wp quick cache by adding these lines to my plugin files:

```
define("QUICK_CACHE_ALLOWED", false); //quick cache
define("DONOTCACHEPAGE", true); //wp super cache
$_SERVER["QUICK_CACHE_ALLOWED"] = false; //quick cache redundant
```